# Общий размер таблиц виртуальной памяти

Tags: memory, x86, memory-management

Есть файл, описывающий структуру виртуального адресного пространства процесса, выглядит это файл, например так:

```
08048000-08053000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 18877      /usr/bin/cat
08053000-08054000 r--p 0000a000 08:03 18877      /usr/bin/cat
08054000-08055000 rw-p 0000b000 08:03 18877      /usr/bin/cat
091e3000-09204000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
4f2d0000-4f2ef000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1857       /usr/lib/ld-2.15.so
4f2ef000-4f2f0000 r--p 0001e000 08:03 1857       /usr/lib/ld-2.15.so
4f2f0000-4f2f1000 rw-p 0001f000 08:03 1857       /usr/lib/ld-2.15.so
4f2f7000-4f4a2000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1858       /usr/lib/libc-2.15.so
4f4a2000-4f4a3000 ---p 001ab000 08:03 1858       /usr/lib/libc-2.15.so
4f4a3000-4f4a5000 r--p 001ab000 08:03 1858       /usr/lib/libc-2.15.so
4f4a5000-4f4a6000 rw-p 001ad000 08:03 1858       /usr/lib/libc-2.15.so
4f4a6000-4f4a9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b75c0000-b77c0000 r--p 00000000 08:03 57661      /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
b77c0000-b77c1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b77d9000-b77da000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b77da000-b77db000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
bf819000-bf83a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
```

Первый и второй столбцы - это соответственно начало и конец отображенной области виртуальной памяти. Вторая - права, третья - смещение в файле, если использовался `mmap`, четвертая - номер устройства - если считывали `mmap'ом`. Пятая - номер файла, если считывали `mmap'ом` и шестая - путь до файла.

В процессорах семейства x86 реализована двухуровневая виртуальная память. Размер одной страницы - 4 кб. Одна корневая таблица страниц (page directory) содержит 1024 записей каждая размером 4 байта, каждая запись может ссылаться на запись второго уровня - каталог страниц (page table). Каждый каталог содержит 1024 записи каждая размером 4 байта.

Вот, и собственно задача, состоит в том, чтобы посчитать общий размер таблиц, необходимый для работы виртуальной памяти для определенного файла. 
Я делаю таким образом: суммарный размер отображенной памяти для файла из примера равен 4345856(я его не полностью выложил), дальше находим количество страниц, их 4345856/4096 = 1061, для них нужно 1061/1024 = 2 директории второго уровня и 1 одна которая на них указывает, в итоге нужно 3*1024*4 = 12288. А в ответе почему-то 7*1024*4. Может я не так что то понимаю, можете объяснить? И рассказать как правильно делать.

Comment: Скорее всего размеры некоторых областей не делятся на 4096. Складывать размеры нельзя. Каждую область надо обрабатывать отдельно.

Comment: @user58697 Вы можете провести вычисления, и если у вас получится то объяснить алгоритм? Полную таблицу сейчас добавлю в вопрос.

Comment: @user58697 Добавил полную версию, если у вас получится, объясните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Виртуальное адресное пространство нужно для того, чтобы ограничивать доступ программ к памяти компьютера. С помощью таблиц виртуальной памяти, по адресу памяти, который есть у программы, получается «физический» адрес этой памяти. Как написано в вопросе, «в процессорах семейства x86 реализована двухуровневая виртуальная память». Это значит, что для получения «физического» адреса из «виртуального», процессор сначала смотрит адрес нужной таблицы второго уровня в таблице первого уровня (которая в случае x86 содержит 1024 записи), и, затем, в найденной таблице второго уровня находит физический адрес нужной страницы, размера 4 Кб.

Например:
программа хочет получить значение, лежащее по адресу 0x01202c37. Адрес таблицы второго уровня (page table, каталог страниц) в корневой таблице записан в первых десяти битах, то есть, в данном случае он равен 0x4, адрес в таблице второго уровня (следующие десять бит) — 0x202. Оставшиеся двенадцать бит указывают на сдвиг внутри страницы памяти, в данном случае он равен 0xc37.

В задании требуется посчитать суммарное количество различных таблиц, используемых для хранения указанных диапазонов адресов. Во-первых, одна таблица есть всегда — это корневая таблица, она занимает 4 Кб. Осталось подсчитать количество таблиц второго уровня (каждая из которых также занимает по 4 Кб). Например, в примере из условия:

```
Диапазон адресов    Диапазон адресов таблиц второго уровня
08048000-08053000   020-020
08053000-08054000   020-020
08054000-08055000   020-020
091e3000-09204000   024-024
4f2d0000-4f2ef000   13c-13c
4f2ef000-4f2f0000   13c-13c
4f2f0000-4f2f1000   13c-13c
4f2f7000-4f4a2000   13c-13d
4f4a2000-4f4a3000   13d-13d
4f4a3000-4f4a5000   13d-13d
4f4a5000-4f4a6000   13d-13d
4f4a6000-4f4a9000   13d-13d
b75c0000-b77c0000   2dd-2dd
b77c0000-b77c1000   2dd-2dd
b77d9000-b77da000   2dd-2dd
b77da000-b77db000   2dd-2dd
bf819000-bf83a000   2fe-2fe
```

Можно заметить, что тут шесть различных адресов таблиц второго уровня:
020, 024, 13c, 13d, 2dd, 2fe.
Соответственно, общий размер всех таблиц — 6 * 4096 + 4096 байт, что и написано в ответе.